# How do I inject spring beans into non-managed beans in a Spring boot console application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I've tried to follow the advice found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects

Only to find that it's compiling but not actually doing what it should. The autowired bean is not being set in the non-managed object.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class SpringApp {

...


public class ApiClient {

    private static String result = "not set";

    //this would be called from another applicaiton written in a different language potentially.
    public String apiInterface(String message) {
        //This is where we're going to have to create Spring, where the languages 'join'.
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringApp.class);
        builder.run();
        System.out.println("Running legacy code...");
        LegacyCode oldCode = new LegacyCode();
        result = oldCode.doLegacyStuff("hello world");
        
        return result;
    }

}


...

@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public class LegacyCode {
    @Autowired
    MessageSender sender; //let's pretend we Spring-fied this bit of code but not the Legacy code that uses it.

    public String doLegacyStuff(String message) {        
        sender.send(message);
        sender.close();       
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "interupted";
        }

        return "ok";
    }
}
```

That's the gist of the code. The full code is over at github here:https://github.com/AlexMakesSoftware/SpringConsoleApp3

The output I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at demo.LegacyCode.doLegacyStuff(LegacyCode.java:13)
        at demo.ApiClient.apiInterface(ApiClient.java:17)
        at demo.DummyApplication.main(DummyApplication.java:7)
```

Which can only mean that the @Autowired MessageSender isn't getting injected.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I should point out that this is a simple example of a more complicated project to slowly integrate Spring into a legacy codebase. I cannot simply 'make it all Spring', nor can I shift the location of Spring's initialisation because this legacy code gets called from another application (albeit a simpler one) written in another language but running in the JVM. Yes, it's horrible, I know.

Comment: Hi , I also tried same followed all steps from baeldung but didn't work. I spent my two days but still harder luck. If you get the solution using AspectJ . Please share the solutions with me. I need to implement this in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not clone your project, just started to take a quick look at your POM in the browser. What immediately jumped at me was this:

Your Maven POM is wrong. You only preconfigure the AspectJ Maven Plugin in the `pluginManagement` section without ever actually declaring the plugin in the regular `plugins` section. I.e., the plugin is not going to be used during your build.

If after fixing that you are still having follow-up problems, I can take a second look.

---

**Update:** What I said before is true, but I also noticed some more oversights in your POM and test code:

- You use a non-existent AspectJ Maven Plugin version.
- For compile-time weaving, you need the AspectJ runtime `aspectjrt` on the classpath.
- You need `spring-tx` on the dependency list, otherwise a class referred to by `spring-aspects` will not be found.
- Your test expects a result different from the actual "ok".

---

**Update 2:** You can simply accept [this pull request](https://github.com/AlexMakesSoftware/SpringConsoleApp3/pull/1).

Comment: I had a little bit of time in order to fix your POM. Please note my updated answer. This answer actually answers your original question without pointing to workarounds like the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is :

You are initializing your `LegacyCode` using `new` keyword. Now problem is that `LegacyCode` uses `autowire` which works only for beans created using Spring. Hence NPE as `@autowired` will not work with `new`.

Solution :

You can mark your `LegacyCode` with `@Component` and then `autowire` it in `ApiClient`. This way `MessageSender` bean will be created and will be available.

Comment: Yes, I could turn the entire app into a Spring app, that would be a solution for this noddy example, but not a solution for the huge legacy codebase I am trying to apply the same logic to. I created this example to demonstrate the problem but the codebase I'm working with is HUGE and I just can't replace all 'news' with autowired beans in one go. I'd be here until Xmas 2030. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you check this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html . You may have already considered but it's worth to point.

Comment: I assume you're reffering to BeanFactoryAware and that I could solve the problem using a sort of static class that holds a reference to the context and fetch the bean out from the non-Spring class - yes that's one way to do it but not a very nice one and makes using Spring pretty pointless in this case.

Comment: Yes, but that is the problem also. Its not Spring entirely too. But I guess, if it is not preferable then it's not.

Comment: We're supposed to be able to use some apsectj magic to inject Spring beans into non-managed objects. If I could get that to work, as I have tried to in this simple example then that would be fine and I'd be reducing the number of inter-dependencies in the code.

Comment: Ok, I will let you know if I can think of any way regarding it.

Comment: Given you an upvote because actually, using ApplicationContextAware was the solution I ended up using. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation must be used in your main class. Thus move it from `SpringApp` to `DummyApplication`.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue but in any case I cannot do that because 'DummyApplicaiton' represents a Scala application calling mine. I have added more information above. In any case, that isn't the solution. I have managed to get Spring working previously without the legacy call and using the same initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use ApplicationContextAware, like so:

```
/** In a perfect world, this wouldn't exist. Maybe one day we can spring-ify everything and this won't need to. */
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

You can then call this in the constructor of your legacy code to retrieve what you need to like so:

```
    public LegacyCode() {
        sender = SpringContext.getBean(MessageSender.class);
    }
```

...and it works.

Ok, you now have a dependency on this SpringContext class but that will go in time if you Spring-ify the entire app and it's not so bad.